# Using aggregator transformation to group a field and check all values per field

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I have a source with the following format:

```
field1(key)  field2  field3     field4
  111          1        1     randomstring
  111          2        1     randomstring
  111          3        1     randomstring   
  111          4        1     randomstring
  111          4        1     randomstring2
  111          1        2     randomstring
  ...
```

There can be any number of field2 and field4 for each field3, and it's possible there may be  multiple occurrences of field4 for a field2.

I want to check all field2 and field4 values for each field3 that exists, and determine if all of  the field4 values are the same.

My first thought was to try using the aggregator transformation to groupby field3, then perform an additional aggregation with a groupby on field4, and compare the Count() between each, but I'm not sure that will work, or is the best way to perform this logic.

---

What I'm trying to understand is after I perform the first groupby on field3, how I check all of the fields for each entry. Could the aggregate function First() be applied here in a sense to grab the first value, then sent as an output to be used in the following filter trans?

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz Sorry left that part out, thanks for catching it. The only check for field2 is the possibility for duplicate entries, as each field2 can have multiple field4 values associated with it.

Comment: I still don't understand fully why you need to achieve. However, here's an advice for `if all of the field4 values are the same` part - in the aggregator create two fields `min_field4` and `max_field4` with the `MIN` and `MAX` aggregate functions - if `min_field4 == max_field4`, the all the `field4` values within a group are the same.

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks Marek. If you could put that as an answer, and add a way to do the aggregation without losing rows that need to be checked, I can mark it.

Comment: Well not lost per say, could have phrased it better. Meant more on the lines of checking in the next aggregation for multiple occurrences of field4. So the MAX and MIN functions work on strings as well? Is that performed the same as ordering/abc?

Comment: Here's a description of `MAX` for strings: *Returns the highest string value found within a port or group. The MAX function uses the same sort order that the Sorter transformation uses. However, the MAX function is case sensitive, and the Sorter transformation may not be case sensitive.* `MIN` works in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Marek, I was able to use your suggestions in my solution.